# Relating two tables with migration in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, migrate

### The goal

Relating `users` table with `users_photos` table.

### The problem

I just don't know how to do.

### The scenario

This is the command line that I express to create the `users_photos` table:

```
rails generate migration CreateUsersPhotos image_url:string thumbnail_url:string user:references
```

It creates the index `user_id`, but there's not any foreign key. I heard about that Rails don't create foreign keys because SQLite doesn't offers support for that feature. It proceeds, right? Maybe [foreigners](https://github.com/matthuhiggins/foreigner) could help, right?

The point is: when I generates the migration and do `rake db:migrate`, any model is created. In other words, just the table is created and I can't interact with the model to add foreign key to it.

### After all, what's the question?

1. When I run `rake db:migrate`, it doesn't create the model. **Why?**
2. How can I add foreign key to `users_photos`? *I need to delete `user_photo`'s entry when a user is deleted.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Migrations do not create model. Run `rails generate model UserPhotos ...` to create both migration and the model. Otherwise you need to create your model manually. Do not worry about foreign keys, rails handle association well enough without them.
2. I personally prefer to do `user_id:integer` in migration, but the way you have it all should work. If you want new model records to be deleted together with their parent, use

   ```
   # User model
   has_many :user_photos, dependent: :destroy`
   ```

Comment: Wow! What a concise answers, thanks! So, in the second answer you quoted a code. Where should I place it? Or better, how should I to place it?

Comment: It is standard association declaration and should be placed inside your User model. It will also create all the setters and readers to handle one-to-many association.

Comment: Ok, so I just have to place at the top of the model and that's it? No terminal commands, easter eggs, etc?

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge - Yep, that's rails! :) It will however expect your user_photos table to have `user_id` column. Also it is a good practice  to keep all association both-directional, so you should add `belongs_to :user` to your UserPhoto model as well. To read more about association see the link supplied by @marvelousNinja.

Comment: Oh, beautiful! Thank you! One last thing: my `current_user` variable has whole user's information that contains in `users` table. In other words, I just can't access `users_photos` so far. How can I access it through `current_user`? *I know, this question is about another subject, but the context is the same.*

Comment: The `has_many` method defines all the readers and setters for association. Just call `current_user.user_photos` to get the list of all associated objects.

Answer (score 1):

**Migrations and models.** Migrations are related to database schema: tables, rows and all that stuff. So, rake db:migrate won't create any models for you. You need to do it by yourself. For example, like this:

```
rails generate model User name:string
```

It will generate appropriate model and migration for you (that migration contains code to generate 'users' table).

**Foreign keys.** Yes, you're right. Rails don't create foreign keys. There're couple of ways of doing that anyway (raw sql). **But these are bad options**. What you can do, is to put that kind of **logic** (deletion of associated records) **inside of model**. Here's a [link to Rails associations guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). You can declaratively state deletion of associated records by something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign foreign key like user has many posts but in post it is saved as author_id

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy, :foreign_key => :author_id
end
```